# jquery change font color

Tags: jquery, input, colors, quotes

How can i change font color from an input value in jquery?

heres my code

```
<h3 id="quoteDiv"></h3>

 <input id="input1" type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Valfri spelare') { this.value = ''; }" value="Valfri spelare"/>

 var quotes = ["(tjej1) exampletext!",];


var user1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;


//Sub in the usernames
                    var ind = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length); //select random quote
                    var newquote = quotes[ind].replace("(tjej1)", user1);


var quotediv = document.getElementById("quoteDiv"); //get the div (or any other element) that you want to display the quote in
                    quotediv.innerHTML = newquote; //display your quote in the div.
```

How can i change the color of value from input1 (tjej1) to green and not the standard h3? I only want the value to change color:)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newquote = quotes[ind].replace("(tjej1)", '<span style="color:green">'+user1+'</span>');
```

Comment: where should i write that?:O

Comment: Wherever between <script> tags :) When do you want to change color?

Comment: That doesnt change the font color in the quote :(

Comment: i want the color to change in the <h3 id="quoteDiv"></h3> not in the input :(

Comment: $('#input').chnage(function(){

   $('#quoteDiv').css('background-color','green');

});

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2ufnK/4/

i want to change the font color from the input to green

Answer (score 0):

You can style your h3 via CSS :

```
#quoteDiv{
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: I only want the value to change color

Answer (score 0):

Jquery keydown

```
$('#input').keydown(function(){

   $(this).css('color','green');

});
```

Jquery keyup

```
$('#input').keyup(function(){

   $(this).css('color','green');

});
```

Jquery chnage

```
$('#input').chnage(function(){

   $(this).css('color','green');

});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2ufnK/4/

i want to change the font color from the input to green

Comment: when you are willing tyo chnage?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2ufnK/4/ check this and try to change the value font color in quotediv, only the value

Comment: No only the value from the input should be green, not the whole quote